# rxjs bundle from unpkg

Tags: angularjs, bundle, rxjs, rxjs5

I have an angular 2.0.0 (same issue in 2.2.0) project. The current dev build generates > 100 http requests.

This is due to it loading non-bundled versions of rxjs..

When I have the following :

```
    map: {
        // our app is within the app folder
        app: 'app',
        // angular bundles
        // snip
        'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
        'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api',
    },
```

The app works but we have 1000+ http requsts , so I try to load rxjs from the bundle, todo this I remove `rxjs': 'npm:rxjs'` and I add the following

Note, for both the npm: loads from unpkg

```
    paths: {
        // paths serve as alias
        'npm:': 'https://unpkg.com/',
        'rxjs/*': 'https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs/dist/global/Rx.js'
    },
```

The ReactiveX git page suggests that this package should work or is it missing something else??

I get the following error with the second config

```
Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is discussed in detail [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9359) and the solution is to use your own loader such as (code credit [nros](https://gist.github.com/nros/311962c6e0ffb67b4e6aada67e1821f0)

Apparently, it's going to be fixed in a future release I suspect this is being held back as rxjs is still in beta.

**rxjsLoader.js**

```
// see: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9359
// in case all parts of RxJS are loaded with a single file (eg: Rx.js), Angular 2 may have
// difficulties using/requiring the various parts.
// this custom loader translates requests to these parts to the already loaded Rx entity.
//
// eg: Angular:
//      require('rxjs/observable/from')  -->  Rx.Observable
//      require('rxjs/operator/concatMap')  -->  Rx.Observable.prototype
//      require('rxjs/util/EmptyError')  -->  Rx
//
// Angular will access 'rxjs/observable/from' as rxjs_observable_from.from
// so, the last part of the included module (eg: 'from') denotes the property name to access
// the required value.
SystemJS.amdDefine(SystemJS.baseURL + "rxjsLoader.js", ["rxjs"], function (Rx) {
    'use strict';

    // custom loader for RX.js to instantiate the correct value
    // see: https://github.com/ModuleLoader/es-module-loader/blob/v0.17.0/docs/loader-extensions.md
    return {
        fetch: function fetch(loadData) {
            return ""; // no fetch - "Rx" is already loaded!
        },

        translate: function translate(loadData) {
            return "";
        },

        instantiate: function instantiate(loadData) {

            // loadData.name contains the full URL
            var propertyName = loadData.name.replace(/^.*\/rxjs-parts\/(.*)$/i, "$1").replace(/\.js$/i, "");

            // if property name is not empty, evaluate and use it
            if (propertyName.length > 0 && !(/^\s*$/.test(propertyName))) {
                var parts = propertyName.split("/"),
                    targetObject = Rx
                ;

                // Angular 2 expects the return value to be an object
                // and the last part of the name to be the property of that object

                for (var i=0; i < parts.length-1; i++) {
                     var partName = parts[i],
                         upperCaseName = partName.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + partName.slice(1)
                     ;

                     // handle special case for "operator/*"
                     if (partName === "operator") {
                         return Rx.Observable.prototype;

                     } else if (targetObject[partName] !== undefined) {
                         targetObject = targetObject[partName];

                     } else if (targetObject[upperCaseName] !== undefined) {
                         targetObject = targetObject[upperCaseName];

                     } else {
                         // skip name and try with next part name. eg: "utils"
                         continue;
                     }
                }

                return targetObject;

            } else {
                // return the Rx as default
                return Rx;
            }
        }
    };
});
```

**systemjs-config-using-custom-rx-loader.js**

```
SystemJS.config({

    baseURL: '/',

    map: {
        "rxjs": "Rx.js"
    },
    paths: {
        "Rx.js/*": "rxjs-parts/*"
    },
    packages: {
       "rxjs-parts": {
            meta: {
                "*": {
                    loader: "rxjsLoader.js"
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a plnkr.io demo for fiddling with RxJS in TypeScript that loads the bundled verison just like you.

See: http://plnkr.co/edit/0o9j6h5GJJiCuBFeWv7f

The important part is `System.config`:

```
System.config({
  transpiler: 'typescript',
  map: {
    'rxjs': 'https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12/dist/global/Rx.js'
  }
});
```

Then importing anything from the bundle with just:

```
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs';
```

Edit:

### The default Angular2 demo updated to load a single `Rx.js`.

See it live: http://plnkr.co/edit/rnO74mQNuPsHAmrIVJ8j

In `systemjs.config.js` I removed the `rxjs` form `map` completely and added to `paths`:

```
'rxjs*': 'https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12/dist/global/Rx.js'
```

Then I'm using it with for example:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<h1>My First Angular App</h1>'
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor() {
    console.log(BehaviorSubject);
  }

}
```

Comment: It is still try to load things from https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12/dist/global/Rx.js/Subject.js and so on... I have no refs other than rxjs eg no imports (I took them out as part of the investigation) I guess something from Angular is loading them???

Comment: I updated my answer with Angular2 demo using bundled `rx.js`

Comment: Thanks, this has been very useful.. But, I still cannot get mine to work.. I have tried adding things like HTTP to your plunk and I have been slowly adding bits but the plunk just keeps working (all though I now get an odd error but it still works, plunk is going it bit slow right now so its hard to carry on I am using Visual Studio and I am compiling the TS within VS. My fork is at http://plnkr.co/edit/7L8gGvp4ymgNM0TsPial

Comment: We'll since my plnkr works then there must be something in your code...

Comment: have  you read this https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9359 as I am getting the same issue , thanks

Comment: @SteveDrake They're talking about `umd` package, me and you are using `globals`, that's `window.whatever...`.

Comment: It looks like it goes wrong once I load in routing, once I load routing I get the `Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined error.