# Typescript import statements for Rxjs operators

Tags: typescript, import, rxjs

I have one Angular project where things like the RxJs library operators,
map,do etc are not imported.  There appears to be no wildcard imports in the source.
Both my Ionic and Angular projects do:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

Then I have an Ionic project which complains if I don't explicity state the imports.

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
```

Furthermore in the Ionic project, I can't seem to locate [refCount](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/refcount.md) in node_modules folders for RxJS either. Though now, I'm beginning to think I need a specific package like rx.lite.js for that... I have no idea how rx.lite.js and and rx.lite-aggregates.js got added to the Angular project in the node_modules folder. I don't get that in my Ionic project. There's not an explicit reference to them in the package.json for the Angular project. Some sort of transitive dependency perhaps?

The Angular project was something I got from a Git repo, so I'm wondering if there is some sort of configuration file that does this somewhere else in the project.
I'm wondering if someone can help shed some light on this mystery for me.

- Angular project package.json rxjs dependency

  ```
  "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
  ```
- Angular project tsconfig.json

  ```
  {
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
      "declaration": false,
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "lib": [
        "es2016"
      ],
      "module": "commonjs",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "outDir": "../dist/out-tsc-e2e",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "target": "es6",
      "typeRoots": [
        "../node_modules/@types"
      ]
    }
  }
  ```
- Ionic project package.json rxjs dependency

  ```
  "rxjs": "5.1.1",
  ```
- Ionic project tsconfig.json

  ```
  {
     "compilerOptions": {
       "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
       "declaration": false,
       "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
       "experimentalDecorators": true,
       "lib": [
         "dom",
         "es2015"
       ],
       "module": "es2015",
       "moduleResolution": "node",
       "sourceMap": true,
       "target": "es5"
     },
     "include": [
       "src/**/*.ts"
     ],
    "exclude": [
      "node_modules"
     ],
   "compileOnSave": false,
   "atom": {
     "rewriteTsconfig": false
   }
  ```

  }

I have been trying to make sense of tsconfig.json. See this [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html)

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43651560/trying-to-understand-rxjs-imports/43652635#43652635 or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39775577/rxjs-bundle-from-unpkg/39788529#39788529

Comment: I read those threads and they didn't really clarify things for me.

Comment: I now suspect that tslint.json is actually responsible for the blacklisting. I see a syntax of the form: "rules:" {"import-blacklist": [true, "rxjs" ]}, in a project started with ng new.

Answer (score 4):

This most likely depends on the structure of your source code.

In general, you should never import from `'rxjs'` and always import a specific module. For example:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

When you do `import { Observable } from 'rxjs'` you're importing `Rx.ts` file that adds all the operators already which means you don't need to call any `import 'rxjs/add/operator/...';` because the operators are already imported.

For example if you have an Angular project and in the root module you add `import { Observable } from 'rxjs'` you'll never need to import any operators separately even though you're not using any `Observable` in the root module at all.

I think your situation is exactly the same. It just depends on where you're importing from `'rxjs'` and if it happens before you try to use any of the operators.

For this reason `angular-cli` by default blacklists importing from `'rxjs'`.

Comment: The reason you should not import rxjs as a whole is that it will add all of Rx to your bundle. Instead, if you import only the operators you need, you get a much smaller bundle. This can increase time to first render and all those sorts of things. During development it might be handy to use the wildcard, however that causes technical debt that you might forget.

Comment: @martin. That doesn't really tally with my experience above. I did an import in both projects with no rxjs prefix on Observable. And each projects is exhibiting differing behaviour. So I think there is something more at play here too. I'm also have found that I can't even find refCount with the explicit add imports either. https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/refcount.md

Comment: @JGFMK `refCount` is not an operator per say. It's a method on `ConnectObservable`, so it doesn't have `add/...`.

Comment: Thanks, refCount now makes sense. But if I imported Observable from rxjs in my Ionic project , why am I having to still explicitly import all the operators in my Ionic project (I appreciate the benefits of explicit imports - but am perplexed as to the differing behaviour).

Comment: @JGFMK I'm not writing your project and I haven't seen it's source code so I can't tell you why it works the way it works. But I recommend you to look at those thing I mentioned here and also be aware that RxJS 4 and RxJS 5 a two different things. For example `rx.lite.js` is from RxJS 4 but from your description you want to be using RxJS 5.

Comment: Ah right. So I'm guessing the Angular project I got from Git was probably written for an earlier build of RxJS originally. Not sure how the other parts were getting incorporated from an npm install, when "rxjs": "^5.1.0" was in the package. From what I can tell about semver in the npm docs, is that would mean any major version 5.1 forward with the caret: See https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver

Comment: I also think that something may have been installed via yarn too - and that has some links back to rx@^4.1.0. The readme.md had some reference to using NuGet http://www.nuget.org/ though that's something outside my current realm of expertise. As you say I think that may now be obsolete.

Comment: The Angular project came from here https://github.com/angular-university/reactive-patterns-course and I'd checked out the error-handling branch

Answer (score 1):

rxJs has a bunch of different import techniques. I was very confused until I read this:
**[Understanding Operator Imports](https://www.learnrxjs.io/concepts/operator-imports.html)**

note that, if you use this import technique (you probably should):

```
import {myOperator} from 'rxjs/operators/myOperator';
```

...to actually *use* `myOperator`, you need to envoke it's `call` method, or pass it in to the `pipe` operator:

```
myOperator.call(parameters);
```

The `pipe` operator seems out of the scope of this topic. Just know that it provides a way to bypass this `.call` syntax and importantly, allows you to effectively chain multiple operators that are imported this way. See the link for more details (really, it's super-helpful).

Lastly, Type Errors abound with rxjs operators in Ionic, especially if you are using angularfire2 (version 5). Sometimes you can resolve these errors by casting the object provided by Angularfire as Observable<..some type..>